# How to find mongodb document by id without a search?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I need to find a document in mongodb using it's ID . This operation should be so fast. So we need to get the exact document which has the given ID . Is there any way to do that . I am a beginner here . So I would be much thankful to you if you could give some in-depth answer

Comment: The "id" is same as `_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so your are really a beginner.

> First thing you should know from now that getting any kind of record
>   from a database is done by a querying the database and its called as
>   **Search**.

It simply means that when you want any data from your database, database engine has to search it in database using the query you provided.

So I think this sufficient to get you know that whenever you ask(using database query) database to give some records from it, it will perform a search based on conditions you provided, then it doesn't matter

1. You provide condition with a single unique key or multiple complex combinations of columns or joins of multiple tables
2. Your database contain no records or billions of records.

**it has to search in database**.

*So above explanation holds true for I guess every database as far as I know.*

**Now coming to MongoDB**

So referring to above explanation, MongoDB engine query database to get result.

Now main question is -  ***How to get result Fast!!!***

And I think that's what your main concern should be.

So query speed (Search Speed) is mainly depend on 2 things:

1. Query.
2. Number of records in your database.

**1. Query**

Here factors affecting are :

**a. Nature of parameters used in a query** - (Indexed or UnIndexed)

If you use [Indexed parameters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) in your query it always going to be a faster search operation for database.
For example the `_id` field is default indexed by mongodb. So if you search document in collection using `_id` filed alone is going to be always a faster search.

**b. Combination of parameters with operators**

This refers to number of parameters used for query (more the parameter, more slower) and kind of query operators you used in query ([simple query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) give result faster as compare to [aggregation query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) with pipelines)

**c. Read Preferences**

[Read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) describes how MongoDB will route read operations to the members of a [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-replica-set). It actually describe your preference of confidence in data that you are getting.

Above are two main parameters, but there are many things such as :

- Schema of your collection,
- Your understanding of the schema (specifically data-types of documents)
- Understanding of query operator you used. For example - when to use $or, $and operators and when to use $in and $nin operators.

**2. Number of records in your database.**

Now this happens when you have enormous data in database, of course with single database server it will be slower i.e. more records more slower.

In such cases [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) (Clustering) your data on multiple database server will give you faster search performance.

MongoDB has [Mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/) component which will route our query to perfect database server in cluster. In order to perform such routing it uses [config servers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/) which stores the meta-data about our collections using Indexes and [Shard-Key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/).

Hence in sharded environment choosing proper shard-key plays important role in faster query response.

I hope this will give you a descent idea of how actually a search is affected by various parameters.

I will improve this answer in future time.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty starlight forward, you can try for the following:

```
var id = "89e6dd2eb4494ed008d595bd";
Model.findById(id, function (err, user) { ... } );
```

Comment: There is a search going on noh ?

Comment: @VCODE NIROSHANA If you want to know how its works internally then you have to look into the `mongoose` or `mongoDB` nom code

Answer (score 0):

with mongoose:

```
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) { // checking if the id is valid
    return res.send("Please provide valid id");
  }
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  Item.findById({ _id: id })
    .then(item=> {
      res.json(item);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }));
});
```

Comment: There is a search going on noh ?

Comment: what do you mean by search? there is a query